# Making Mac backups on cloud services

Tags: macos, google-drive

Is it possible to make a Time-Machine-like (or indeed use Time Machine) to make a Mac backup on cloud services? I just got unlimited Google Drive storage and 1TB on Box and incidentally, my physics external drive stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to keep in mind is that the Google Drive client carves out local storage and synchs that "drive" to Google's cloud storage. It's more honest to call it Google Sync than Google Drive, but I'm not a marketing guy...

The official word from Cupertino is no, this won't work. Time Machine does not back up to network drives, except Time Capsules or a drive running Leopard or Snow Leopard on another Mac on the same local network. It will often back-up to a USB drive connected to an Airport Extreme, but even that is technically unsupported.

#### Here's the official word: *http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1733*

But given all of that, I'd have to wonder if mounting a network shared Google Drive from *another Mac* would work. Granted, you'd need another Mac but if you're really want to try this out, I'd see if that works.